# Solving magic squares in Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm new to Z3 and as an exercise attempted a magic square solver by adapting an existing sudoku solver ([http://lauri.võsandi.com/tub/qaoes/z3.html](http://lauri.v%C3%B5sandi.com/tub/qaoes/z3.html)). I supply no facts (i.e. no specific numbers in specific boxes) other than the sum of all rows, columns and main diagonals are equal and entries are distinct and in the range [1,N*N]. It works fine for squares up to size 4. Any higher though and I give up waiting for a solution.

Is this normal? Or would experienced z3 programmers suggest my implementation has issues as problems of this size should be solvable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better results by expressing the entry in each cell as a `BitVec()` variable rather than an `Int()` variable.

See https://github.com/0vercl0k/z3-playground/blob/master/magic_square_z3.py for an example implementation.  That implementation is able to find a solution for a 5x5 magic square in 1 second, a 6x6 magic square in 13 seconds, and a 7x7 magic square in 24 seconds (on my computer), so it seems to be doing significantly better than your formulation.